# "The behavior is seen in other properties" vs. "for other properties"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> The same behavior can also be seen [in/for] other properties such as the color and the mass.

Which one is correct here, *in* or *for*?

EDIT: Adding more context:

> The charge of quarks increases as we move to the heavier region. The same behavior can also be seen [in/for] other properties (of the quarks) such as the color and the mass.

Comment: You'd need to provide a more complete context for a definitive answer, but my guess is *usually* it would be better to use "**with**". I also think that in most contexts it would be largely a stylistic choice anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks for the comment, is there enough context now?

Comment: Not for me, no. What "behaviour"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, what about now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "in."  Or, depending on the larger context, "with," as [FumbleFingers says in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132320/choosing-in-vs-for#comment273693_132320). Either way, don't use "for" there.